# Laravel: Check if slug in a route is equal to slug in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have an url like `/locations/name-of-the-location.ID`

My route is:

```
Route::get('locations/{slug}.{location}', ['as' => 'locations.show', 'uses' => 'LocationsController@show'])->where([
    'location' => '[0-9]+', 
    'slug' => '[a-z0-9-]+'
]);
```

Now I want to check if the slug provided is the same that is saved in the database column 'slug' with my model (because the slug may have changed). If not, then I want to redirect to the correct path.

Where is the best place to do that? I thought of \App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider- but when I try to use `Route::currentRouteName()` there, I get NULL, maybe because it is 'too early' for that method in the boot() method of RouteServiceProvider.

What I could do, is to work with the path(), but that seems a bit dirty to me, because I work with route prefixes in an other language.

Here's what I tried (I am using a little helper class `RouteSlug`) - of course it does not work:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    if (strstr(Route::currentRouteName(), '.', true) == 'locations')
    {
        Route::bind('location', function ($location) {
            $location = \App\Location::withTrashed()->find($location);
            $parameters = Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameters();
            $slug = $parameters['slug'];

            if ($redirect = \RouteSlug::checkRedirect(Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName(), $location->id, $location->slug, $slug))
            {
                return redirect($redirect);
            }
            else 
            {
                return $location;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: why not put this in `LocationsController@show` ?

Comment: I also use the slug on edit, destroy and other methods. I also have slugs in other controllers, so I want to mange all the redirects in 1 place.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I came up with a Middleware:

App\Http\Middleware\CheckSlug

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($redirect = RouteSlug::checkRedirect(Route::currentRouteName(), $request->location->id, $request->location->slug, $request->slug))
    {
        return redirect($redirect);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

My route look like this:

```
Route::get('locations/{slug}.{location}', ['as' => 'locations.show', 'uses' => 'LocationsController@show'])->where([
    'location' => '[0-9]+', 
    'slug' => '[a-z0-9-]+'
])->middleware(App\Http\Middleware\CheckSlug::class);
```

Comment: You should register your middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I am going to improve that tomorrow. For now I am happy that my solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Your route should look like this:

```
Route::get('locations/{id}/{slug}', ['as' => 'locations.show', 'uses' => 'LocationsController@show'])->where([
    'id' => '[0-9]+', 
    'slug' => '[a-z0-9-]+'
]);
```

And `LocationsController@show` should look like this:

```
public function show($id, $slug)
{
    // Add 'use App\Location' to the top of this controller
    $location = Location::find($id);

    // I'm not sure what you were doing with the soft deleted items
    // but you might want to restore them if you are using them
    if ($location->trashed()) $location->restore();

    if ($slug != $location->slug) {
        return redirect()->route('locations.show', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $location->slug]);
    }

    // Return the view

}
```

Comment: No, my route should be exactly as postet in my Question. I also use Route-Model Binding, so no need for `$location = Location::find($id);`

Comment: Route model binding is only useful if you intend to return the model only, are you making an API?

Comment: I use route model binding in order to also get the soft deleted models when i type hint them in my controller.

Comment: I don't think you're grasping how that is used, but I guess you found what you are looking for. Route model binding "should return the instance of the class that should be injected into the route".